# React Navigation - Abstract useNavigation hook and use setOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

So I'm trying to abstract away React Navigation's useNavigation hook so that

1. I can call something more specific like `setBackButton()` instead of `navigation.setOptions({...})`
2. If we move to a different system in the future, I only need to make changes in one place.

However, when I tried doing this, I could never get it to work. For example:

```
// custom navigation hook
const navigation = useNavigation()

const setBackButton = () => {
   const parent = navigation.getParent()
   if (parent !== undefined) {
       parent.setOptions({
          headerLeft: ()=> <Button>Test</Button
       })
   }
}
```

When I try calling this in my screen, it has no effect on the button.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? Is there any error?

Comment: @LinDu There's no behavior; no errors thrown.